# How to substitute Realm in Xamarin.Forms Windows Phone project

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, realm

I intend to create a Xamarin.Forms project with local data storage features.

For storing the data, I'd like to use the new [Realm](https://realm.io/) library that is available for Xamarin.Forms projects - *except it does not support the Windows Phone project which is part of the Xamarin.Forms project*.

I don't want to abandon it yet, so I look for options about what I could do.

As Realm supports Android and iOS, I would use them in those projects and somehow *hide the use of the database classes* with an interface or abstract class like this:

In the PCL project I'd have an interface like this:

```
public interface IDBOperations<T>
{
   List<T> GetData();
   void SaveData(T input);
}
```

And use it with `DependencyService` like this:

```
DependencyService.Get<IDBOperations>().SaveData(myModel);
```

In another PCL project, I'd have a *model* like this:

```
public class Model1: RealmObject
{
   public int ID {get; set;}
   public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

In the Android project:

```
public class DBOperations<T>: IDBOperations<T>
{
   public List<T> GetData()
   {
     //get data from Realm
   }
   public void SaveData(T input)
   {
     //save data with Realm transaction
   }   
}
```

In the Windows Phone project:

```
public class DBOperations<T>: IDBOperations<T>
{
   public List<T> GetData()
   {
     //get data from SQLite
   }

   public void SaveData(T input)
   {
     //save data with SQLite transaction
   } 
}
```

Is my approach correct? Or should I entirely use SQLite and forget this?

Answer (score 1):

I admit that this is not obvious at the moment. Trust me that we are planning UWP (Windows Phone) support and hoping to be able to deliver it soon but until then, the approach that you have started seems sound. The Realm "paradigm" differs slightly from the traditional ORM style, so you might run into some difficulties trying to create a common abstraction. We do not yet have real experience doing this ourselves, so we don't know exactly what the pitfalls are. I'll be happy to help you along the way.

Comment: Thanks for your promised support :) For now, I don't use Realm but I implemented the database operations via an interface so it will be easy to replace the ORM layer. Can you estimate when the UWP support will be available?

Comment: Fair enough. Sorry, I can't give a timeline at this point, but you can keep track of the issue here: https://github.com/realm/realm-dotnet/issues/509

Answer (score 0):

It's probably a bit late, but this may be useful for others.

I'm the author of [MarcelloDB](http://marcellodb.org), which is a mobile object database built for Xamarin and UWP.
Functionality-wise, it is quite like Realm, except it only works for the .net platform.

I think a common abstraction between these two databases is quite feasible, so you can replace MarcelloDB with Realm once Realm supports UWP.